# How would i echo out my session array from codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know this question has been asked before but my session array is set up different and i would liuke to be able to echo out 'firstname', and 'email' in my members view.

Here is what my session array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => 0be663ae77530e5992d3116af24a216d
    [ip_address] => 
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36
    [last_activity] => 1421547754
    [user_data] => 
    [email] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => Travis
            [email] => theller5567@gmail.com
            [password] => 894027e71b85d60bcc5b0dbe6e83f1f6
        )

    [is_logged_in] => 1
    [firstname] => 
)
```

I want to get to the email array and echo out the firstname.
any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

this is my function that sets the userdata. if you see a better way of doing it please by all means share, i would be very greatfull.
public function register_user($key){

```
$this->load->model('model_users');
        if($this->model_users->is_key_valid($key)){
            if($newemail = $this->model_users->add_user($key)){
                $data = array(
                    'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
                    'email' =>  $newemail,
                    'is_logged_in' => 1
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect('login/members');
            }else echo "Failed to add user, please try again.";
        }else echo "invalid Key";
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I can think to access it would be this:

```
$email = $this->session->userdata('email');
```

Then you can echo the info inside of it with:

```
echo $email['firstname'];
```

and

```
echo $email['email'];
```

From what I can see, CodeIgniter's session library doesn't have any direct ways to access multidimensional array values.

Comment: I didnt make the array like that on purpose, i was trying to get the firstname to store in the session data and that is the only way i was able to get it in. I was able to make it work with the code you gave me so thank you.

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked out! And there's no issues with the way you are putting things in the session, CI just doesn't have any direct ways to access things like that, at least that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'firstname: ' . $_SESSION ['email']['firstname'];
echo 'email: ' . $_SESSION ['email']['email'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @misunderstood but i was looking for the codeigniter way plus i don't think that would actually work if i used the $_SESSION.